# XSLT rounding issues

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, rounding

There is a very strange issue that we are facing with XSLT rounding and Format-number functions. Lets say I have a number like 131.855 and I want to round it off to two decimal places. I expect 131.86 as the answer but XSLT round() function rounds it off to 131.85. I tried using "round(131.855*100)div 100" but it doesnt work. Whereas if I have to round off a number like 127.855 it does get rounded off correctly to 127.86 using the same code i.e. "round(127.855 *100)div 100". Also, strangely if I try to round off 131.755 it does get rounded to 131.76!! Very strange.
We also tried using format-number() function but that also gives weird results. For instance, if I take number 349615.225 and I use format-number on this i.e. format-number(349615.225,'#.##') it gives 349615.22 whereas I expect decimals to be .23. But if I use format-number on 131.855 it does get converted to 131.86...

I have also tried using round() function inside format-number() but it also gave the similar results..

We are using XSLT 1.0. Changing to XSLT 2.0 seems a tough task. Only workaround I see is to use some java function and call it from within XSL for rounding off.

Any ideas will be highly appreciated.

Edit:

Strangely enough exactly same issue happens with Java's Math.round function.

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: This appears to be an error caused by floating point arithmetic. I have managed to reproduce the problem in both Xalan  http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y8S and Saxon http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y8S/1 - but curiously not in libxslt, so this could be a Java engine issue.

Comment: "*same issue happens with Java's Math.round function.*" Well there you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

`format-number(round(100 * $number) div 100, '#.00')`

The `round()` function rounds the number to the nearest integer, and just use of `round()` may not round the number properly.
The `format-number()` formats the number by trimming the data(I guess), which can cause in loss of value.
Use of both `round()` and `format-number()` shall affectively work.

Below example depicts the different behaviours.

Input:

```
<root>5.225</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="round(*)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="round(100 * *)"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(*, '#.00')"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(round(100 * *) div 100, '#.00')"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Output:
5
523
5.22
5.23

Comment: "*The round() function rounds the number to the nearest even number,*" No, it rounds to the nearest integer, and it always rounds half **up**. --"*The format-number() formats the number by trimming the data,*" The behavior of the function is not well-defined in the spec and you will find different processors implement it differently (though I don't know of one that truncates).

Comment: Yes, I'd to be careful when I said `even` :) let me update my answer.. The `format-number()`, was my assumption by the way it behaves.. Thanks @michael.hor257k!

Comment: We have tried this option as well on 131.855 but it doesnt work..For testing I m using the default XSLT processor in Eclipse

Comment: @SandeepArora Did you find a reliable way to round up the values after this issue? I know it's an old thread, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that when you write a number like 131.855, the actual value that it represents is not exactly half-way between 131.85 and 131.86. There is no double-precision floating point number that is numerically exactly equal to 131.855, so the actual value you are manipulating is slightly below that or slightly above. This inexactitude arises as soon as you write the number down, it doesn't only arise when you do arithmetic on it. When you multiply it by 100, this difference gets magnified, and when you use round(), it will go to the nearest integer which will depend on whether the approximation was up or down in the first place. So given that XSLT 1.0 only offers floating-point numbers, there is no way of avoiding this kind of problem.

In XSLT 2.0 you can use decimal numbers, which behave more the way that human beings tend to expect.

Comment: Then why 127.855 rounds off to 127.86 and 131.755 rounds off to 131.76?

Comment: It's unpredictable whether the number you get will be higher or lower than the number you write. On my system, when I write 127.855, the number I get is 127.8550000000000039790393202565610408782958984375, while when I write 131.755, the number I get is 131.7549999999999954525264911353588104248046875